# Get last h1 tag before clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, closest

When a user clicks an element on a page, I need to find the closest `h1` tag above the clicked element and get it's html content.

**Given the below html:**

```
<div>
  <h1>This is header 1</h1>
  <div>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span style="color:red;" class="myClass"> CLICK ME</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
  </div>
   <h1>This is header 2</h1>
  <div>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
     <span> some text</span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I tried:**

```
$("body").on('click', '.myClass', function() {

        var text=$(this).closest( "h1" ).html();
        alert(text);

});
```

But `text` ends up `undefined` as it doesn't find the h1 tag

**Expected result:** function should alert "This is header 1"

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/son6v8g3/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`closest` should be used to get the closest *parent* of the element, then get the [*previous sibling*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
var text = $(this).closest('div').prev('h1').text();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/son6v8g3/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
 var heading = $(this).parents('div:first').prev('h1').text()
```

Comment: `parents` is obviously an overkill here.